# Удалятся ли объекты сборщиком, если они имеют перекрестные ссылки?

Tags: java, сборщик-мусора

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Подскажите, соберет ли сборщик два объекта, если на них нет внешних ссылок, кроме как друг из друга?

Пример кода:

```
public class SomeClassA{
    private referenceToB;
    public SomeClassA(){
        referenceToB = new referenceToB(this);
    }
}

public class SomeClassB{
    private SomeClassA referenceToA;
    public SomeClassB(SomeClassA referenceToA){
        this.referenceToA = referenceToA;
    }
}
```

Comment: конечно соберет

Comment: Да, потому что объекты не являются доступными (на них нет внешних ссылок).

Comment: в данном случае можем сказать, если один из этих объектов имеет `root reference`, например используется в Thread stack, их нельзя будет удалить. Как только они потеряют связь с каким либо видом корневых ссылок, такие объекты (которые циклически указывают друг на друга) будут помечены на удаление